# Passing objects to user control and + Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, user-controls

My problem is that.. i have a UserControl, on which i have placed a DataGridView and a button.
On this Control i have this three variables:

```
namespace MySpace
{
    public partial class PanelWithDataGrid : UserControl
    {
        public DatabaseMenager FDatabaseManager { get; set; }
        public SqlCeDataAdapter FDataAdapter { get; set; }
        private DataTable FDataTable { get; set;  }
        [...]
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
public PanelWithDataGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

And.. i have a method that looks like this:

```
public void Initialize(DatabaseMenager pDatabaseManager, DataTable pDataTable, SqlCeDataAdapter pDataAdapter)
        {
            FDataAdapter = pDataAdapter;
            FDatabaseManager = pDatabaseManager;
            FDataTable = pDataTable;
        }
```

And.. i also have a button that has a click event that looks like this:

```
private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Accept changes?", "Accept?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    FDataTable.AcceptChanges();
                    FDataAdapter.Update(FDataTable);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error:\n\n{0}", ex.StackTrace));
            }
        }
```

And now to the point:

1. In the form that owns this component i run the "Initialize" method.
2. It displays the data that i wan't it to display.
3. Then I change some values in the cells in the datagridview.
4. But when i click on the "accept" button of this control which should
   accept the changes and update the datatable that which is connected
   to the datagridview - there's an error that says "Object reference not
   set to an instance of an object."

Please help..

Comment: When is Initialize() called?  This is most likely a problem with the page lifecycle, where Initialize() is being called after the btnAccept_Click method.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the location of the failure and look at the variable values. Any nulls?

Comment: asawyer:  FDataTable.AcceptChanges(); 

This Control is created by putting it on to a form called "AdminPanel"
in the AdminPanel i have a constructor that looks like this

`InitializeComponent();
            
pwdgvWorkers.Inicialize(FDatabaseManager, FDatabaseManager.FAdmin_WorkersDataTable, FDatabaseManager.FAdmin_WorkersDataAdapter);`

Comment: The variables are nulls, but in the Admin panel that owns this control  the variables are accesible ;/

Comment: `FDatabaseManager.FAdmin_WorkersDataAdapter` is null. Work backwards into the `FDatabaseManager` to see why.

Comment: Oh my God... In the AdminPanel I was calling a method `FDatabaseManager.ConnectSourceWtihTable_Admin_Worker(pwdgvWorkers.GetDataGridView());` which was creating the dataadapter etc. after the `Initialize` method.. 
It works :)

Comment: @JackRz. Write that up as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @asawyer i can't anwser my own questions as a new user ;/ i must wait 7 hours from now

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

This component - `PanelWithDataGrid` - was placed on a component called `AdminPanel`.

The `AdminPanel` was executing a method  `Initialize` which was passing the data adapter and the data table to the the PanelWithDataGrid component. Those variables were null becouse they were created after the `Initialize` method..

So the solution to this problem is creating the object that is a `SqlCeDataAdapter` and another one that is `Datatable` before running the `Initialize` method.